# How to draw a column graph after adding all positive and negative values for a specific 'year' in geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I have a `data frame` contain some information for a period of (1948-2013). Every year also contains data in terms of `4 season`. Now sometimes, the year contains `positive` and `negative` data. Sample of my data

```
   YEAR Region               temp_avg_max temp_avg_min temp_dif_avg_max whole_avg_min_temp
     <int> <chr>                       <dbl>        <dbl>            <dbl>              <dbl>
     1  1948 Central egion                33.1         20.6          -0.400              -0.516
     2  1948 Eastern Region               32.7         19.1          -0.775              -2.08 
     3  1948 Northern Region              33.5         20.2           0.0124             -0.970
     4  1948 Northsouthern Region         33.5         21.3           0.0443              0.154
     5  1948 Northwestern Region          31.6         20.9          -1.88               -0.232
     6  1948 Southeastern Region          32.5         21.8          -0.958               0.676
     7  1949 Central egion                33.1         20.6          -0.400              -0.516
     8  1949 Eastern Region               32.7         19.1          -0.775              -2.08 
     9  1949 Northern Region              33.5         20.2           0.0124             -0.970
     10 1949 Northsouthern Region         33.5         21.3           0.0443              0.154
     11 1949 Northwestern Region          31.6         20.9          -1.88               -0.232
     12 1949 Southeastern Region          32.5         21.8          -0.958               0.676
```

Now I want to draw a `column graph` and I also did it. My code is given below

```
plot_diff_max_temp_vs_year_region_col <- ggplot(data=diff_max_temp[diff_max_temp$YEAR %in% c(1948, 1960, 1972, 1984, 1996, 2008, 2013),], 
                                       aes(x=Region, y=temp_dif_avg_max, fill=factor(YEAR)))+
 geom_col(position="identity", width = 0.5)+
 geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%0.1f", round(year_wise_region_max_temp, digits = 2))), 
 position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.50)+
 theme_minimal()+
 xlab("Region")+
 ylab("Temperature")+
 ggtitle("Max Temp with 12 years moving ")
```

You can take a look at my graph in hear [online plot link](http://%5B!%5BScreenshot-from-2020-10-12-20-43-10.png%5D(https://i.postimg.cc/JzLGxf13/Screenshot-from-2020-10-12-20-43-10.png)%5D(https://postimg.cc/Mv96KrfX))

However, I want to draw them in this way (all negative and positive values will be added) for a specific `Region` and then will draw the `column`.

Any guidelines are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ggplot2 2.2.0` `negative stacking` is possible.

Just remove the `geom_text` and changing something minor. Find the code

```
plot_diff_max_temp_vs_year_region_col <- 
ggplot(data=diff_max_temp[diff_max_temp$YEAR %in% c(1948, 1960, 1972, 1984, 1996, 2008, 2013),]
                                       )+
geom_col(aes(x=Region, y=temp_dif_avg_max, fill=factor(YEAR)))+
 theme_minimal()+
 xlab("Region")+
 ylab("Temperature")+
 ggtitle("Max Temp with 12 years moving ") 
ggplotly(plot_diff_max_temp_vs_year_region_col)
```

I am not sure but you can take a look at this link [Link](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/improved_bar_stacking_ggplot2_220/)